# How to display category and sub category in asp.net using database

Tags: query-string

I need to display item from category and sub category.
Ex. category is Mens and Subcategory is footwear, shirts, T-shirt, Ties.
So when the customer clicks "shirts", all shirts images should be displayed.
So can you share me the logic for the same in ASP.net.

i have tried the below code.
Product.aspx.cs

```
string qr;
   string category;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(qr!=null && category!=null)
        {
        qr = Request.QueryString["category"].Trim();
        category = Request.QueryString["sub_cat"].Trim();
        //sub_category = Request.QueryString["sub_category"].Trim();
        }

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
           disp();
         }
    }
    Class1 cc = new Class1();
    public void disp()
    {
        if (category == "'Fabrics'")
        {
            DataList1.DataSource = cc.dis_diplay("select pname, images from product_entry where category=" +qr).Tables[0];
            DataList1.DataBind();
        }

And the code for Product.aspx
```

'" title='Linen'>Linen

Answer (score 0):

Entering your question into Google provided a step-by-step tutorial on the first page of results that seems to do what you want: http://www.nullskull.com/a/1555/using-datalist-to-list-categorysubcategory-with-expand--collapse-facility-via-javascript.aspx